# Excel String - search and ordering with VBA

Tags: string, excel, vba, pivot

looking for a starting point for my task.

Situation:

I have three Excel worksheets that have the same structure and contain the following columns amongst others:

```
|ID|SubID|SubName|Description|Link1|Link2|
|1|1|SubName 1|Desc SubName1|P00001|P00002|
|1|2|SubName 2|Desc SubName2|P00002|P00003|
|2|1|SubName 1|Desc SubName1|P00001|P00002|
```

here comes a line that contains more than one P-Number inside a cell:

```
|3|1|SubName 1|Desc SubName1|P00001,P00002,P00003|P00001,P00002|
```

I now would like to look through the Link1 column and place those values with the first three columns in a sorted order to a "Link1" worksheet like so:

```
|P-Number|ID|SubID|SubName|
|P00001|1|1|SubName 1|
|P00001|2|1|SubName 1|
|P00001|3|1|SubName 1|
|P00002|1|2|SubName 2|
|P00002|3|1|SubName 1|
|P00003|3|1|SubName 1|
```

And I would like to do the same with the Link2 column also placing the values to a seperate worksheet.

The next step would be to concatenate the P-Number of the new sheet with a string that works like a link. That's what I have working so far.
Another idea would be to make the SubName clickable and have it jump to the according name in one of the three worksheets.

I'm not sure if a macro is the right choice or maybe a Pivot table could also do the trick.

Any ideas are appreciated.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
I tried to incorporate this concept to my main macro where I also process the columns mentioned above. However since I have several loops running through this part the output line will be over-written by the last P-number of the column. I use this Sub:

```
 Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
  End Sub
```

And this call for testing:

```
PrintArray NewArray, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Link 1").Range("A2")
```

How can I "save" each P-number to the new sheet without having to use a loop inside my code?

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables can't split 1 cell into multiple rows, so the starting point of a VBA solution would be:

1. load input range into an array (`my_array = Range(...).Value2`)
2. for each row, split Link1 (`link_array = Split(my_array(current_row, 5), ",")`)
3. for each link, append the link and other values into a results array
4. place the results onto a worksheet
5. sort the resulting range